# Will reflected light, from a mirror, work on plants?

Tags: sunlight

There is a space in our house where we would like to put plants in, however, the closest window is about 15ft away and only from one side. I was wondering if adding mirrors, to the darker side to reflect the light, would help.

Comment: Interesting question.  In artificial grow rooms we make sure the walls are white or reflective to use all the energy produced by the lights.  But the lights have to be there.  I have to go look up the reduction of energy when reflected.  Those light tubes using mirrors don't add heat.  They do get light into tiny spots.  (I'd start looking into artificial grow lights...you won't believe the choice and prices!)

Comment: You should get 95%+ reflection of most wavelengths a plant is interested in using your typical aluminumized mirror. Nice chart of reflectivity vst wavelength here: https://www.edmundoptics.com/resources/application-notes/optics/metallic-mirror-coatings/ Plant pigment absiorption spectra here: https://support.heliospectra.com/portal/helpcenter/articles/which-regions-of-the-electromagnetic-spectrum-do-plants-use-to-drive-photosynthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it should work. White should also work (theoretically), and I know that for some fruits (melons) aluminium sheets are used, "to enlighten the dark side". These two last methods have the advantage that the light is diffused (instead of being converged in few points).

Sun is "diffuse" but strong, and mirror will just simulate it. On the other hand, the plant will not receive so much sun (farther for windows, less time to get direct sun to the plant), so the plant could be not be customized to receive so strong sun light (and in few points).

Answer (score 6):

It's not going to help. As the sun apparently moves across the sky you're going to have to track where the sun light falls into the room and position mirrors to focus the reflection on your plants. You would need something like a heliostat. The [Sunflower Home Heliostat](https://www.fastcompany.com/1680592/a-mirror-system-that-brings-sunlight-into-the-darkest-corner-of-your-home) is a good example of what I mean.

Better to get plants that don't require much sunlight for that corner of the room.